# aviso para in_array vindo vazio

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, relatório

tenho um código que para gerar um PDF ele checa o que está marcado no checkbox. Porém se eu não marcar nada, ele ainda sim abre o PDF, só que apenas com a folha em branco. Tem como fazer um **`if`** que se caso não tenha sido marcado nada, mostre um alerta na tela para o usuário. Meu código está escrito em Codeigniter, e na **view** do relatório tem o seguinte código:

```
if (in_array("foto", $itens)) {
     //código para mostrar a foto se está marcada a opção no checkbox
}
```

No meu controller está:

```
$itens = $this->input->post('itens');
        if (!empty($itens)) {
            $data['itens'] = $itens;
        } else {
            $data['itens'] = array(null);
        }
 $this->load->view('ViewDoRelatorio', $data);
```

Comment: experimente dar um `die();` ou `exit();` antes de gerar o código, e depois da exceção.

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu coloquei mas não apareceu nada de diferente

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu coloquei o teu código de resposta e realmente funcionou, isso corrigiu outro erro que eu tinha. Acho que me expressei mal, não era exatamente esse erro que eu tinha falado. Muito obrigada do mesmo jeito, com o código que me enviou corrigi outro erro que havia.

Answer (score 2):

Para tratar o erro, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
function seuMetodoQueGeraPDF() {
   /* seu codigo vem dentro do seu método,
      e para qualquer condição de erro, 
      você cria uma exceção. */
  if (!in_array("foto", $itens)) { 
      throw new Exception("Marque a opção selecionada"); 
   }
}

try {
//dentro do "try" você executa seu método de gerar PDF.
 seuMetodoQueGeraPDF();

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: Depois de gerada uma exceção nada mais é executado, assim sendo o `die` não está a mais ?

Comment: é mania. hehehe

Comment: +1 pelos comentários no script e pela simplicidade.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito o uso do bloco try catch para isso, assim ao invés de você criar um vetor passando null você cria um erro tratado.

> Exemplo do código

```
<?php

try {
  $itens = $this->input->post('itens');
  if (!empty($itens)) {
     $data['itens'] = $itens;
  } else {
     throw new Exception('Erro: marque alguma opção!');
  }
  $this->load->view('ViewDoRelatorio', $data);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
     echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```